# Remote connect to database at demo.phpmyadmin.net?

Tags: php, sql

I teach a little php and SQL and I would like my students to temporarily connect to a database they have testet on demo.phpmyadmin.net, is this done simply by using:

```
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $hostname = "192.168.30.23";
```

If so it doesn't seem to work for me. :)

Comment: Are the login details correct? Are you sure of the IP?

Comment: your hostname may be '77.78.107.253'

Comment: maybe external IP blocking issue. Check if remote access allowed or not.

Comment: Did anyone find the soultion? I also want to connect to this same db